# SQL Find all courses who have more students enrolled then the allowed enroll_limit for the course

Tags: sql

I'm currently taking a database class and I am stuck on a homework problem due tonight

Find the courses given in the ‘Sloan’ building which have enrolled more students than their enrollment limit. Return the courseno, enroll_limit, and the actual enrollment for those courses.

I'm stuck trying to count how many students are in each course.

```
CREATE TABLE Course ( 
courseno   VARCHAR(7), 
credits    INTEGER NOT NULL, 
enroll_limit INTEGER, 
classroom   VARCHAR(10), 
PRIMARY KEY(courseNo), ); 

CREATE TABLE Student ( 
sID   CHAR(8),
sName   VARCHAR(30), 
major VARCHAR(10), 
trackcode   VARCHAR(10), 
PRIMARY KEY(sID), 
FOREIGN KEY (major,trackcode) REFERENCES Tracks(major,trackcode) );

CREATE TABLE Enroll ( 
courseno    VARCHAR(7), 
sID   CHAR(8), 
grade FLOAT NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (courseNo, sID), 
FOREIGN KEY (courseNo) REFERENCES Course(courseNo), 
FOREIGN KEY (sID) REFERENCES Student(sID) );
```

My current very broken attempt is

```
SELECT sloancourse.courseno 
FROM course sloancourse 
WHERE 
    sloancourse.classroom = 'Sloan' 
    and sloancourse.courseno IN ( 
        SELECT c.courseno 
        FROM student s, enroll e, course c 
        WHERE 
            c.courseno = e.courseno 
            and s.sid = e.sid 
            and sloancourse.courseno = c.courseno 
    )
;
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> postgresql. I removed the conflicting tags, please add only the relevant one.

Comment: My current very broken attempt is SELECT sloancourse.courseno FROM course sloancourse
WHERE sloancourse.classroom = 'Sloan' and
sloancourse.courseno IN (
    SELECT c.courseno FROM student s, enroll e, course c
    WHERE c.courseno = e.courseno and s.sid = e.sid and sloancourse.courseno = c.courseno
); I have no idea how to work add a column to each course say like "enrollcount" and then compare enrollcount to enroll_limit in the course table.

Comment: Break it down into pieces. How do you count enrollments? Seems like you start with the Enroll table. For a course, where do you find the limit on enrollment? The Course table. So join them and count. Presumably you're learning about (or probably have learned) joins and aggregating.

Comment: And no - we don't join in the FROM clause any longer. Don't learn it, don't practice it. Run from any course that is teaching it.

Comment: Smor I tried to take your advice, but I'm having such a heard time understanding how I would "loop" over each course and count the students in that course. Using your advice I came up with this pathetic attempt. SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM course
INNER JOIN enroll ON enroll.courseno = course.courseno
;

Comment: How about this?

select courseno, enrolelimit, count(*) as enrolled
from course, enroll
Where
course.courseno = enrole.courseno and
course.classroom = "salon"
group by courseno, enrolelimit

Comment: Learn to use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Answer (score 0):

> Find the courses given in the ‘Sloan’ building which have enrolled more students than their enrollment limit. Return the courseno, enroll_limit, and the actual enrollment for those courses.

You would typically `join` courses and enrollment (using *stanard* join syntax, with the `on` keyword), `group by` course, and finally filter on courses whose student count with a `having` clause.

```
select
    c.courseno,
    c.enroll_limit,
    count(*) actual_enrollment
from course c
inner join enroll e on e.courseno= c.courseno
where c.classroom = 'Sloan'
group by c.courseno, c.enroll_limit
having count(*) > c.enroll_limit
```

Note that you don't need to bring in the `student` table to get the desired results.

Comment: Shouldn't you add `HAVING`?

Comment: @GMB Could you explain to me the purpose of the group by. I feel that is the source of all my confusion in this problem. I'm not sure what it's accomplishing and why you used it? Wouldn't the c.courseno be unique in the returned rows? Unless...the returned rows are all the enrollment statements, which means counting how many times each courseno appears is also how many enrolled students enrolled in each class. Is that the answer?

Comment: @JakeGergen: the join produces one record per course and enrolled stuent. `group by` gives you one record for each course. `count(*)` is the number of records in the group, hence the number of students of the course.

Comment: @GMB Very well explained. I understand completely how you arrived upon your answer and why your answer works. Thank you, kind soul, for not only solving my problem but gracefully walking me through the solution. I hope karma find's you well.

Comment: @JakeGergen: welcome, and thanks for your prayings. If my answer properly responded to your question, then [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) by clicking the check sign... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT 
  Course.courseno,
  Course.enroll_limit, 
  Couse.classroom
FROM Course, Enroll 
WHERE Course.courseno = Enroll.courseno
AND Course.classroom = 'Sloan'
GROUP BY Course.courseno
HAVING count(*) > Course.enroll_limit
```

Postgres docs have an example on these aggregate functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-agg.html

Basically, when you group by one or multiple properties, the resulting table will result in a unique row for the property/combination of properties. In this example, you would have one row for each of the `courseno` unique values (as they are grouped by this value).